# why is my code giving a run time error?

Tags: c++

The code is fine as such according to me. I have tried debugging it line by line and unexpectedly this code is giving me a run time error and I have not been able to understand why such an error is been given by this code. Can someone go through the string functions I have used here and please if possible tell me why this program is giving a run time error?
The ideone link for this code is http://ideone.com/LyFTWu

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int t,i;
//printf("md");
scanf("%d",&t);
for(i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    int n,j,k,f,g=0;
    char a[50][57],c[50];
    //printf("me");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //printf("%d",n);
    //m=getchar();
    //printf("me\n");
    getchar();
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        k=0;

        while(1)
        {

            a[j][k]=getchar();
            //printf("%c",a[j][k]);
            if(a[j][k]=='\n') break;
            k++;
        }
        //printf("me\n");
    }
  for(j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
  {
  k=0;
  g=0;
    if(j==n-1)
    {

        printf("Begin ");
    }
    else if(a[j+1][0]=='L')
    {
        printf("Right ");
    }
    else if(a[j+1][0]=='R')
    {
        printf("Left ");
    }
        while(1)
        {

        while(a[j][k]!='o'&&g==0)
        {

            k++;
        }
        g=1;
        //printf("me");
        if(a[j][k]=='\n') break;
        printf("%c",a[j][k]);

        k++;


        }
    printf("\n");


  }
}
return(0);
}
```

Comment: what is the error and where ?

Comment: Where does it give a run-time error exactly and what is the run-time error you see? This code also seems to be C rather than C++.

Comment: *"The code is fine as such according to me."* - Well I suppose that settles it.  If only you could convince your computer.

Comment: see the input here at this link http://www.codechef.com/COOK29/problems/DIRECTI

Comment: Since you're using C++, you could use the std::string class and probably make the code more readable and easy to debug. Character arrays can of course be made to work, but they're quite a bit more work to get right.

Comment: Hmm. I am running it now for the 4th time, and it does not crash. But I dont know what it wants to do. Maybe it will incarnate father christmas, but I could'nt figure out which parameters to enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I see is that you access in `while(a[j][k])` the array whith k==-1, which is not a legal index.

Comment: well you are right for sure but the real problem was that I copied the input from the input given to test in my code and when copying the input u dont get the return in the input which was creating a problem and i got it now..

Comment: refer to this ideone link http://ideone.com/P3KU24 and still same problem is being faced.........

Comment: Hmm, I pasted the input (that with the roads) to stdin of your program. It digests it happily, but wants to read more.

Comment: see this link now.......with slight modifications I was expecting an output but well see to it.....http://ideone.com/5CCp4E

Comment: Haha, I've run that thing from within gdb. It's stuck in the loop `while(f==0&&a[j][k]!='\t') {c[k]=a[j][k];k++;}`, and is happily incrementing k, but I think by accessing c out of bounds, at some point it overwrites k and thus (at least for my compiler) is in a strange endless loop.

Comment: the updated code is fine now.......thanks for your time.....

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things I spotted:

1. Using `scanf()` requires that you check if it successfully read the fields, using, e.g., `scanf("%d", &n) == 1` and handling both outcomes approriately.
2. If `50 <= n` the first loop access values out of range for `a[j][k]`.
3. If the line is longer than `57` the access to `a[j][k]` is also out of range.
4. `a[j][k]` is accessed with `k == -1` which is out range, at the other end this time.
5. The nested `while`-loop starting with `f == 0` can access out of range values all over the place if there is no `\t` character on the line.

I'd guess, I could find more errors if I'd gaze furhter at this mess...

Comment: well the range problem should not be there as I have taken ranges keeping input in mind..........

Comment: No.1 rule of programming: Users will try hard to f*** you over. Even if friendly users don't, hostile users will abuse any buffer overrun. Not checking against array overruns is the primary attack vector.

Comment: well u are right for sure but do refer to the input which I have given in the ideone link http://ideone.com/P3KU24....for this input it shouldnt be a problem

Comment: Use of the index `k == -1` definitely *is* an error!

Comment: http://ideone.com/P3KU24 did you refer to this link........

Comment: There is no need to refer to this link beause the expression `a[j][k]` with `k == -1` is unconditionally executed. If you feel to have other code analysed you need to update your question as they are meant to be self-contained.

Comment: Also, the inner loop checking for `\t` looks as if it won't terminate with your input (unless there is a hidden `\t` at the end of each line). Fix the problems I have pointed out and check if the problem goes away!

Comment: \t is used to detect spaces in between aphanumeric characters.......

Comment: Did you fix the problems I pointed out? Also, you didn't answer where the problem actually occurs.

Comment: actually the approach which I have used to solve is not very good I should have used gets() instead of getchar() and instead of \n I should use \0 and the problem which was coming is runtime error so was difficult to find out......

Comment: You *shall* **never** use `gets()`! If anything, use `fgets()`. `gets()` is the well-known approach to deliberately overrun buffers: It doesn't take any boundary and, thus, it is prone to overflow errors (and it is said to be one of the major approaches for people to inject code).

Comment: finally did debug it............updated the correct code......

Answer (score 1):

`while(f==0&&a[j][k]!='\t')` is never true (well, it may be, but not in your input - unless you have other input than on the site you linked to)

This is clearly a problem, as you will overrun the end of your buffer and keep going until something else goes wrong.

Comment: well it will be true as a[j][k] is storing characters and when the space character comes up for the very first time after the first word it will be true...correct me if i am wrong...

Comment: `'\t'` is not "space". It is a tab character. I tried your code, and with a small change to this line, it works better - it's not perfect, but it's a lot better. I didn't figure out why it's not perfect, as I didn't really fancy spending hours trying to sort through your code that uses single character variable names and is rather poorly formatted. Try making names that actually mean something, that way it's much easier to follfow the code. And declare one variable on each line. Disk space isn't so expensive these days.

Comment: well I do appreciate your effort a lot but I made this code for a short coding contest so didnt make any meaningful longer variable names and if you could briefly explain any bugs you found in this code I will be highly grateful......

Comment: If you are in a "shortest code" competition, then write the code using long names, then shorten them once it's working - at least if you plan on asking random people who are not in the same competition for advice. Sorry, your code is too messy to read - and you have been given other comments as well to similar effect.

Comment: one thing which you pointed out that \t is for tab but then what is used for spacebar?

Comment: `' '`? 

I just wrote, from scratch, an your code is 11 bytes longer than mine, despite me using longer names - and it works... I'm sure I could shorten it, but life is a little too short for that kind of silliness. <Scratch that - 70 bytes shorter, just spotted a little saving by not setting a variable several times>

Comment: I just added my code as an 'answer', even if it's not quite an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

My working entry for the "obfuscated C competition" (yes, I'm sure it could be made more obfuscated, and I had it down to 397 characters, but decided for this variant, as it makes more fun use of macros):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define L "Left"
#define R "Right"
void s(int*p){if(scanf("%d ",p)!=1)exit(1);}
#define c(a,c)if(!strncmp(a,r[i],c))
#define f(a,b,c)for(i=a;i b;i c##c)
int main(void){int t,n,i,o;char r[40][51],*x,*d;s(&t);while(t--){s(&n);
f(0,<n,+)fgets(r[i],50,stdin);d="Begin";f(n-1,>-1,-){o=5;c(L,4)o=4,x=R;
else c(R,5)x=L;printf("%s%s",d,r[i]+o);d=x;}puts("");}return 0;}
```

It's reasonably safe (doesn't say much if you enter wrong inputs tho', and will do "strange" thigs if the lines are longer than stipuladed). I should add a check for if(t>40)exit(1); perhaps.

Feel free to indent properly and try to figure out how it works. ;)